# Calculate center of mass multiple integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, mathematical-physics

Can you help me with this problem?

Find the center of mass of a lamina whose region R is given by the inequality:
[image]

and the density in the point (x,y) is :

[image]

The region r is this one:

[image]

Is this the proper way to set up the integral for m:

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-x-1}^{x+1} \ e^{x+y} \ dy \ dx$$

Any help?  Thanks

Comment: If answers to your question don't fully resolve your problem, either request further clarification from the answers' owners, or ask a new question about the _specific point_ you are having trouble with. *Do not* simply re-ask the same question.

Answer (score 1):

The integral for total mass is $$\int_{xmin}^{xmax}\int_{ymin}^{ymax} \delta(x,y) \ dy \ dx$$ where the range $(xmin,xmax)$ is the whole range of the shape and the range $(ymin,ymax)$ is the range in $y$ at a given $x$.  Can you put the correct limits on?  Can you do the integral?

Comment: I can do the integral but I don't know how to put the correct limits. My answer would be x= 0 to sqrt(2) and the same with y, but I'm sure that is wrong

Comment: What is the maximum value that $x$ can have anywhere in the region?  What is the minimum value that $x$ can have?  Those are the outer limits.  Then the $y$ limits come at a particular $x$.  So if $x=\frac 13$, what is the range of $y$.  Draw a picture and the $y$ range is the vertical line segment from the bottom to the top of the figure.

Comment: I've tried for a while and can't seem to get it. Can ou help me a little more

Comment: $|y| \ge 0$, so let it be zero.  What values can $x$ assume?  Can $x$ ever be any greater?  Now, if $x=\frac 13$ what can $y$ be?

Comment: Given your figure, which is correct, what is the greatest $x$ in the region? What i the least?

Comment: -1<= x <= 1 ? same for y?

Comment: if x = 1/3 then y = 2/3

Comment: You are correct for $x$.  It is true that $y$ ranges over $[-1,1]$, but the question here is what is the range for a given $x$.  I chose $\frac 13$ as an example. What is the range of $y$ when $x=\frac 13$?  You need to write functions $ymin=f(x), ymax=g(x)$  Then $f(x), g(x)$ are the limits of the inner integral.  For your last, no, because of the absolute value signs $y$ can be positive or negative, and because of the $\le$ relation it can be smaller.

Comment: so y= +- sqrt((x-1)^2) ?

Comment: No, everything is linear here, so we won't have square roots.  You are correct that the maximum $y$ when x=\frac 13$ is $y=\frac 23$.  The minimum $y$ is then $y=-\frac 23$. It is easier if you split the $x$ integral into two, one from $-1$ to $0$ and one from $0$ to $1$, as you know the effect of the absolute value on $x$ in each interval.  Let's think about the integral over $x$ from $0$ to $1$.  Again, given $x$ in that range, what it the minimum $y$ and what is the maximum $y$?  You should express it as $ymin(x)=..., ymax(x)=.....$ You are looking for the equation of the boundary lines.

Comment: it would be y = -x + 1 from x = 0 to 1

Comment: That is the top limit, the lower is $y=x-1$  The lower integral is similar.  Now you have the integral set up.  You integrate in $y$ first, assuming $x$ is fixed, then integrate in $x$

Answer (score 1):

Draw an $s$-axis like so: $\nearrow$, and a $t$-axis like so: $\nwarrow$. Then the blue square appears in $(s,t)$-coordinates as
$$Q=\left\{(s,t)\>\biggm|\>|s|\leq{1\over\sqrt{2}}, \ |t|\leq{1\over\sqrt{2}}\right\}\ .$$
Due to symmetry the center of mass has $(s,t)$-coordinates $(\sigma,0)$, where it remains to determine $\sigma$. Since $x+y=\sqrt{2} s$ we have to solve
$$\sigma\int_Q e^{\sqrt{2}s}\ {\rm d}(s,t)=\int_Q s\>e^{\sqrt{2}s}\ {\rm d}(s,t)\ .$$
This immediately reduces to
$$\sigma\int_{-1/\sqrt{2}}^{1/\sqrt{2}}e^{\sqrt{2}s}\>ds=\int_{-1/\sqrt{2}}^{1/\sqrt{2}}s\> e^{\sqrt{2}s}\>ds\ .\tag{1}$$
Computing the integrals in $(1)$ leads to
$$\sigma={\sqrt{2}\over e^2-1}\ .$$
Therefore the $(x,y)$-coordinates of the centroid are given by
$${1\over e^2-1}\>(1,1)\ .$$

Answer (score -1):

Rotate the entire thingy by angle $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Integrations will be
$$\int_{-1/\sqrt{2}}^{+1/\sqrt{2}}dx\int_{-1/\sqrt{2}}^{+1/\sqrt{2}}dy \;\;\delta'(x,y)$$
etc. where
$$\delta'(x,y) = \delta\left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{-x+y}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=e^{y\sqrt{2}}$$